# How do I check if a field in SQL table is less than the average of another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have two SQL tables that I have created using these create statements:

[image: create1]

[image: create2]

Which has given me the tables:

[image: Advertisement Table]

[image: Adverting_Campaign]

I want to create a query that returns the AdvertName and Theme fields if the CampaignCost is less than the average cost of the CostEstimate in the 2nd table.

I am a bit  confused and have tried:

`SELECT advertisement.AdvertName, advertisement.Theme
 FROM advertisement 
 WHERE advertisement.CampaignCost < 
 avg(advertising_campaign.CostEstimate);`

but I get an Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function. 
I am quite new to SQL so I am unsure how I should approach this question... any guidance would be appreciate :)

Comment: It seams you are looking for a subquery here like `.... WHERE 
 advertisement.CampaignCost < (SELECT 
                                 AVG(advertising_campaign.CostEstimate)
                               FROM   
                                 advertising_campaign
                              )`   If this does not help or you can't get it working... See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was exactly what I needed. I have tried to add more info to the question so that it is more clear, my apologies!

Comment: Do you know why I can't choose your comment as the answer?

Comment: Yes a comment is not considerd to be a answer so you cant accept it

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the query I needed to write was:

```
 SELECT advertisement.AdvertName, advertisement.Theme
 FROM advertisement 
 WHERE advertisement.CampaignCost < (SELECT AVG(advertising_campaign.CostEstimate)
 FROM advertising_campaign);
```